# Finding your reputation % in meeting reputation milestones

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm trying to find the chart that lists the reputation point value with the capability granted and how many % you are in getting there.  The way to get there has apparently changed or I have forgotten.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`/privileges`](https://serverfault.com/privileges) <-- it's a link, really, you just can't tell with Meta's color scheme :-)

It's apparently on the drop-down you get when you hover over your username on the main site too:

[image: Obligatory Red Circle Meta Image is Obligatory]

Comment: Used to be that you clicked on something on a standard SE website, and it was linked to that.  Guess it got changed somewhere along the line.

Comment: I think clicking on your reputation used to take you there.  If you hover over your username on the main site there's a little `privileges` link at the top of the rep score card that should take you there (obligatory red circle photo coming shortly)

Comment: Now we know who you down voted!

Comment: @MarkHenderson That's not true - there are TWO answers on that question with negative scores :-)

Comment: Mine doesn't look like that at all. There's no red highlighting or arrow and it doesn't say "Click me".

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Your monitor must be broken. [I think it's a stuck pixel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yTe6yEhgBw) <- Foamy Cartoon, possibly not safe for work, especially if you tend to laugh at tech support jokes.

Comment: I never heard of Foamy before. I'm just having breakfast, so this has started my day with a smile. Thanks. :)